# Como funciona align-content e align-items?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Se entendi direito `align-content` só tem efeito quando `flex-wrap: wrap` está aplicado deixando o contêiner flex em multilinhas, enquanto o `align-items` só funciona quando é uma única linha, seria isso?

Comment: Sobre o `align-content`, sim, ele não tem efeito se for uma linha. Sobre o `align-items` funciona com uma linha ou múltiplas, claro que o efeito resultante disso será diferente, veja: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYmdi.png (a esquerda com wrap, a direita sem)